# I Have A Dialog That Displays But Only One Button Changes the Cursor

Tags: javascript, html

I have what is probably an incredibly simple question, but I don't know how to resolve it and any help would certainly be appreciated.

Here's my code;

```
<div id='div2'>
    <div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox" id="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
    <h2>Got A Bike to Sell?</h2>
    <p class="BikeForSaleButton">
    <a href="http://somepage.com">Yes</a>
    </p>

    <p class="BikeForSaleButtonNo">
    <a onclick="javascript:var div = document.getElementById('div2');div.parentNode.removeChild(div);">No</a></p> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

For a reason unbeknownst to me, the "No" link is not changing the cursor to a hand when hovered over but I haven't a clue how to address this.

I would suspect the problem is arising because the NO link doesn't have a href but being that I'm very novice I don't know how to remedy the situation so I ask that someone could please show me how to resolve this and I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

because you have no href attribute on the link. Add one and the cursor will change.

NITPICk: drop the `javascript:` it is not needed.

Comment: You guys are Awesome!! I'll be working on making these changes and getting rid of the JS and I thank you both again!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `href ="#`" to make it look like a link and not to navigate to a different page

```
<div id='div2'>
    <div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox" id="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
    <h2>Got A Bike to Sell?</h2>
    <p class="BikeForSaleButton">
    <a href="http://somepage.com">Yes</a>
    </p>

    <p class="BikeForSaleButtonNo">
    <a onclick="javascript:var div = document.getElementById('div2');div.parentNode.removeChild(div);" href ="">No</a></p> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The onclick event handler needs to supress the links default behavior to navigate to what's specified in the href attribute.

so you need `href="#"` also you dont need that `javascript:`
It should be like this:

```
   <p class="BikeForSaleButtonNo">
    <a href="#" onclick="var div = document.getElementById('div2');div.parentNode.removeChild(div);">No</a></p>
```

Here is a link to show the **working code:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dkU7B/1/

**Edit:** Forgot to mention another thing you can do is get rid of the onclick entirely and just use the href with javascript like so, but now you will need to use the `javascript:` just a neat trick.

```
<a href="javascript:var div = document.getElementById('div2');div.parentNode.removeChild(div);">No</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an href="#", and I would separate your HTML and JS, it's just cleaner IMO:

```
<script>
var div = document.getElementById('div2');
    function rmv() {
         div.parentNode.removeChild(div);
     }
</script>

<div id='div2'>
    <div class="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox" id="DoYouHaveADirtBikeForSaleBox">
        <h2>Got A Bike to Sell?</h2>
        <p class="BikeForSaleButton">
            <a href="http://somepage.com">Yes</a>
        </p>

        <p class="BikeForSaleButtonNo">
        <a href="#" onclick="rmv()">No</a></p> 
</div>
</div>
```